# Correct way to read data for a graph

Tags: django

What i want to do is to show some data in a graph. the data is from a pandas data frame that i generated in my main.py file when crunching some numbers.
Now i want to show this in a chartsJS graph in another html.

Is the correct way to leave my data frame that i generated in my main.py file and generate the graph by looking at the main.py file an reading the data frame. or is the correct way to generate a django model and have the graph read the data from a django model?
The data frame will change everyday, hence the graph will be changing daily.

If the latter is correct could someone show me how they would make the model if the data frame is just some text with numbers

```
print(df["my_data"])
pass: 20
fail: 50
n/a: 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic overview. Let me know where you need elaboration.

**views.py**

```py
def chart(request):

    # chart.js data structure created in python:
    data = {
        "labels" : ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", ...]
        "datasets" : [
            {
                "label" : "series 1",
                "data" : [0, 1, ...],
                "backgroundColor" : "blue"
            }, 
            ...
        ]
    }

    # send as JsonResponse:
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**script.js**

```js
$.ajax({
  url : "the/url",
  type : "GET",
  success : function(response) {
    chart = new Chart("<the identifier>", {
      type : 'bar',
      data : response,
    });
  }
})
```